# Android Firebase, retrieve data from firebase database

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I'm just trying to get the name data. But It's a little bit confused.

How can i get only name data above data tree.

Comment: can you post what you done till now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userId=user.getUid();
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user_study_condition");

reference.child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
   String name=datas.child("name").getValue().toString();
     }
 }
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
 });
```

Here the snapshot is at the child(userId), then you iterate inside it's direct children to be able to get the name value.

Comment: I'm sorry I checked in late. The answer is really works for my problem! Thank you!